# How to know if a date is the previous month or earlier?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm looking for some conditions to start billing my clients. 
Every time that my client make a contract with me, i initialize a date in the attribute start_billing_at. I'd like to know now, if the start_billing_at attribute has been initialized during the previous month. Hope that my problem is more clear now

Thx for help

EDIT

I'v got to know if my date is between the first and the last day of the previous month

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please add more so that we can understand and help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, based on Michael kohl solutions

```
def calcul_bill(date)
  if Time.zone.today.last_month.strftime('%b, %Y') == date.strftime('%b, %Y')
    #Do actions
  else
    #Do other actions
  end
end
```

My date format is "Wed, 30 Aug 2017" is this case, so i just compare Month and year

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two dates and calling `to_i` on it will give you the difference in days, you can switch on that:

```
if (Date.today - other_date).to_i < 30
  # less than a month
else
  # more than a month
end
```

Of course this doesn't exactly follow the months, but for my use cases it's generally good enough.

Another alternative is:

```
if date_to_check > Date.today.last_month
  # within the last month
end
```

Or checking for inclusion in the range of last month's dates:

```
last_month = Date.today.last_month
(last_month.beginning_of_month..last_month.end_of_month).cover?(date_to_check)
```

Comment: This could be a solution is think, but what about mont of 31 days ?

Comment: The second approach is a bit smarter, i.e. `Date.new(2017, 3, 31).last_month #=> Tue, 28 Feb 2017` (it goes to the 28th, not the 31st). I'll add one more option for you, wait for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
%w|2017-07-01 2017-06-01|.map do |d|
  (Date.today.month - Date.parse(d).month) % 12 == 1
end
#⇒ [true, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I would go for:

```
start_billing_at.beginning_of_month == Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month
```

With a refinement you could define a method on date that allows you to:

```
start_billing_at.last_month?
```

So:

```
module BillingDateExtensions
  refine Date do
    def last_month?
      self.beginning_of_month == Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month
    end
  end
end
```

... and you can allow this to be mixed in to Date where you need it with:

```
using BillingDateExtensions
```